# Addressable::URI - get url without any parameter

Tags: ruby

```
url = Addressable::URI.parse("https://my.url?with=a&lot=of&parameters")
```

How do I get the base url without ANY query parameter, without knowing which parameters or how many there are?

I can't do `url.query_values = {}` because I also need the original url at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to use [`omit`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/addressable/Addressable%2FURI:omit):

> `Addressable::URI#omit(*components) ⇒ Addressable::URI`
>
> Omits components from a URI.

```rb
url = Addressable::URI.parse('https://sub.example.com/path/to/foo?x=1&y=2#hash')

url.omit(:query).to_s
# =>
"https://sub.example.com/path/to/foo#hash"
```

If you also don't want the hash or other components, pass them to `omit` as well:

```
url.omit(:query, :hash)
```